# leetcode 574 winning candidate query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Please see the picture for** [ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARfDB.png)

Table: Candidate

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | Name    |
+-----+---------+
| 1   | A       |
| 2   | B       |
| 3   | C       |
| 4   | D       |
| 5   | E       |
+-----+---------+
```

Table: Vote

```
+-----+--------------+
| id  | CandidateId  |
+-----+--------------+
| 1   |     2        |
| 2   |     4        |
| 3   |     3        |
| 4   |     2        |
| 5   |     5        |
+-----+--------------+
id is the auto-increment primary key, CandidateId is the id appeared in Candidate table.
```

Write a sql to find the name of the winning candidate, the above example will return the winner B.

```
+------+
| Name |
+------+
| B    |
+------+
```

Notes:
You may assume there is no tie, in other words there will be at most one winning candidate.

**Why this code can't work? Just try to use without limit**

```
SELECT c.Name AS Name
FROM Candidate AS c 
               JOIN 
                   (SELECT r.CandidateId AS can, MAX(r.Total_vote) AS big
                    FROM (SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(id) AS Total_vote
                          FROM Vote
                          GROUP BY CandidateId) AS r) AS v
ON c.id = v.can;
```

Comment: But it works : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdecd6/1

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan When I submit solution at Leetcode, the system told me it's wrong. The system provided a different table. I just added the screenshot. Can you tale a look?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't understand, either. Perhaps there exist some product spesific components other than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, here: `SELECT r.CandidateId AS can, MAX(r.Total_vote) AS big`

you use `MAX` aggregate function, without `group by`, which is not correct SQL.

Try:

```
SELECT Candidate.* FROM Candidate
JOIN (
    SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(id) AS Total_vote
    FROM Vote
    GROUP BY CandidateId 
    ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC LIMIT 1
) v
ON Candidate.id = v.CandidateId
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `join`/`group by` query with `order by`:

```
select c.name
from candidate c join
     vote v
     on v.candidateid = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Name AS Name
FROM Candidate AS c JOIN (SELECT r.CandidateId AS can
                      FROM
                       (SELECT CandidateId, COUNT(id) AS Total_vote
                        FROM Vote
                        GROUP BY CandidateId) AS r
                      WHERE r.Total_vote = (SELECT MAX(r.Total_vote) FROM (SELECT 
CandidateId, COUNT(id) AS Total_vote
                        FROM Vote
                        GROUP BY CandidateId) r)) AS v
ON c.id = v.can;
```

**This is updated code**

My code has two errors. The first one is "use of an aggregate like Max requires a Group By clause if there are any non-aggregated columns in the select list", but not sure why my previous code still can run and show no error. Maybe the system add the group by function automatically when it run.

The second one is that max can't be used with Group by in this format.